# How to make bootable pendrive for Kali Linux in UEFI system?

Tags: system-installation, kali-linux, live-usb, uefi, bootable

I tried making a bootable pendrive for Kali Linux in order to dual boot Kali Linux with Windows using Rufus on my laptop. I am using GPT drive and UEFI system. But Rufus gives the error that the ISO image does not support efi system. So how do I make a bootable pendrive for efi system?

Answer (score 1):

Download [Kali 2016.1 Rolling Edition](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-rolling-edition-2016-1/) it supports UEFI and in Rufus choose the option in which MBR and UEFI are both defined.